# Change Arabic font in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I tried to change the font inside android studio but arabic font cant change it ! Can you help me please . Font for editor not for mobile application.

[image]

Comment: You tried `Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Font` ?

Comment: @Quinn Yes I tried many time that change English font only .

Comment: I tried pasting some Arabic into the demo box and some of the fonts seemed to change it, I'd imagine you just need to pick a font that supports Arabic letters

Comment: @Quinn , Oh thank you so much , its better now I picked english font that support  Arabic letters and now its clear to see.

Comment: try explicitly changing it in the style.xml

Comment: @Emotional_Goose Hummmmmmmmmmmmm , Wow\

Comment: changing the font to monospaced helped

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: change arabic font in android studio]

the problem is the main font you use is not support arabic so , 
go to `

> File>setting>Editor>Font

` and change fallback font to any other font like times new roman or any preferred one .

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer but it may help. You couldn't change it directly, you have to customize it by downloading a font in .ttf format. Then identify it in the style.xml file.
For more, you can find the steps here
https://github.com/AreejTurky/Custom-Font-Android-Project